Run MMI query on Ubuntu 2022 with .NET 8
I'm testing Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure (MMI) https://github.com/PowerShell/MMI.
The code works fine on Windows, but it does not work on Ubuntu.
Ubuntu version: 22.04.4 LTS
Environment preparation:

Installed .NET 8 runtime
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-runtime-8.0


Installed OMI
wget https://github.com/microsoft/omi/releases/download/v1.9.0-0/omi-1.9.0-0.ssl_300.ulinux.s.x64.deb
sudo dpkg -i omi-1.6.10-1.ssl_300.ulinux.x64.deb


I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable in command window from which I run the .NET 8 app
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/omi/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH



When I run app ./WmiOnLinux, I get following error during MMI query:

Could not find the resource "Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Strings.resources" among the resources "" embedded in the assembly "Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure", nor among the resources in any satellite assemblies for the specified culture. Perhaps the resources were embedded with an incorrect name.

I'm publishing dotnet app like this:
dotnet publish .\WmiOnLinux\WmiOnLinux.csproj -c Release -r linux-x64

The code:
CimSession session = null;

try
{
    session = Connect();
    var networks = session.QueryInstances(
DefaultRootNamespace, "WQL", "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");

    foreach (var network in networks)
    {
        var ipObj = network.CimInstanceProperties["IPAddress"];
        network.Dispose();
    }

    session.Close();
    session.Dispose();
    session = null;

    return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");

    if (session != null)
    {
        session.Close();
        session.Dispose();
        session = null;
    }

    return false;
}
...

private CimSession Connect()
{
     WSManSessionOptions options = new WSManSessionOptions();
     options.UseSsl = true;
     options.CertCACheck = false;
     options.CertCNCheck = false;
     options.CertRevocationCheck = false;
     //DComSessionOptions options = new()
     //{
     //    Impersonation = ImpersonationType.Impersonate
     //};

     CimCredential credentials = new(
         PasswordAuthenticationMechanism.Default,
         string.Empty,
         settings.Credential.UserName,
         settings.Credential.SecurePassword
     );
     options.AddDestinationCredentials(credentials);

     CimSession mySession = CimSession.Create(settings.TargetIP.ToString(), options);

     return mySession;
}
...

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (object sender, X509Certificate? certificate, X509Chain? chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) =>
    {
        return true;
    };

